# How can I use an object from a lambda expression in a different lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have this code

```
service.confirm(identity, id)
                .map(confirmationResponse -> InternalToExternalResponse.mapToExternal(confirmationResponse))
                .map(externalResponse->uriBuilder.buildAuthorizeUri(externalResponse))
                .lift(auditOperatorFactory.logRequestURI(identity, AuditCategory.BOOKKEEP));
```

Now i need to extend the `uriBuilder.buildAuthorizeUri(externalResponse)` to take `confirmationResponse` as a second parameter

Can I use the `confirmationResponse`  from the first lambda expression inside the second lambda expression? the final code should be like

```
service.confirm(identity, id)
                .map(confirmationResponse -> InternalToExternalResponse.mapToExternal(confirmationResponse))
                .map(externalResponse-**>uriBuilder.buildAuthorizeUri(externalResponse,confirmationResponse ))**
                .lift(auditOperatorFactory.logRequestURI(identity, AuditCategory.BOOKKEEP));
```

Comment: No you can't. you can set `confirmationResponse` in `mapToExternal()` method result. or mix two `map` in one `map` operation.

Comment: What are the result types of your `.confirm()` and `.buildAuthorizeUri()` methods?

Comment: @Amadán, ConfirmationResponse  and ExternalResponse

Comment: What does `ConfirmationResponse.map()` do and return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `confirmationResponse` to the next lambda as the result of this one. Since you need both, you can either create a custom object or use `Pair` like this:

```
service.confirm(identity, id)
                .map(confirmationResponse -> new Pair<ConfirmationResponse, ExternalResponse>(confirmationResponse, InternalToExternalResponse.mapToExternal(confirmationResponse)))
                .map(result ->u riBuilder.buildAuthorizeUri(result.second, result.first ))
                .lift(auditOperatorFactory.logRequestURI(identity, AuditCategory.BOOKKEEP));
```

Comment: All the other answers are correct, but I picked this because I don't want  to mix the lambda expressions

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the two lambda expressions:

```
service.confirm(identity, id)
                .map(confirmationResponse -> {
                    ExternalResponse externalResponse = InternalToExternalResponse.mapToExternal(confirmationResponse);
                    return uriBuilder.buildAuthorizeUri(externalResponse,confirmationResponse);})
                .lift(auditOperatorFactory.logRequestURI(identity, AuditCategory.BOOKKEEP));
```

I'd suggest using shorter lambda variable names, though:

```
service.confirm(identity, id)
                .map(cr -> {
                    ExternalResponse er = InternalToExternalResponse.mapToExternal(cr);
                    return uriBuilder.buildAuthorizeUri(er,cr);})
                .lift(auditOperatorFactory.logRequestURI(identity, AuditCategory.BOOKKEEP));
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not merge into a single lambda?

```
service.confirm(identity, id)
       .map(confirmationResponse -> uriBuilder.buildAuthorizeUri(InternalToExternalResponse.mapToExternal(confirmationResponse), confirmationResponse))
       .lift(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use the `confirmationResponse` in the second lambda. That would break the functional pattern.

You can include it in the first lambda's result, though. Just create youself a utility class like `Pair`:

```
service.confirm(identity, id)
       .map(confirmationResponse -> Pair.of(
           InternalToExternalResponse.mapToExternal(confirmationResponse), 
           confirmationResponse))
       .map(p -> uriBuilder.buildAuthorizeUri(p.getFirst(), p.getSecond())
       ...
```

I am not sure though, if that's good style here.